# How to make Jenkins job fail in case of java exception?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, hudson

I have Jenkins job. I run maven java-executor plugin as follows:

compile exec:java

here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.proj.utills</groupId>
    <artifactId>db-upgrade</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.proj.db.RunMe</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>
                            ${TARGET_ENV}
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I would like that Jenkins job fail when I got exception in Java code. For now it success even in case of exception. How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [log parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin)

**EDIT:** Excerpt from the plugin's documentation

```
Job Configuration
Go to menu: Jenkins -> job name -> Configure
Go to section : Post-build Actions
Check the "Console output (build log) parsing" checkbox.
"Mark build Unstable on Warning" option: check to have parsed warnings mark the build 'unstable'.
"Mark build Failed on Error" option : check to have parsed errors mark the build 'failed'.
"Select Parsing Rules" : select the set of rules to use for parsing the logs of this job's builds
(Notice that this list is derived from the global configuration )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano how does this not answer the question? I guess Syon may be right, it's just when I answered I thought it pretty much was self explanatory. As a proof of concept please see Peter's answer below

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) for cases like this. just configure what you are looking for. In your case it might be as simple as looking for 'Exception'. I used to parse the output of shell scripts, to find sql errors (but still ignoring some that I don't care about).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [Jenkins Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin), downgrade the BUILD status from successful to UNSTABLE/FAIL when the regular expression setting is met. More detail refer to the link above.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem and did not like this parsing log solution.
For me a -B (to enable the batch mode) did the work nicely

build: 
  - mvn -B deploy